# Change an activity from another

Tags: android

I have two activities.The first has some layouts and the second has a switch/toggle.What i want to do is when i change the toggle from the second activity to hide the layouts in the first activity.
Now,i know i can use SharedPreferences but i find it hard to believe that i can't reference stuff from one activity in another.
For example : howcan i call a method from activity A in activity B?
How can i like modifiy a textView from activity A in activity B? Like,pressing a button in activity B to change a textView in activity A directly,not thru SharedPreferences or anything like that.
Isn't there some way to reference it ?
I'm probably gonna need to do this and i can't believe it isn't possible.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following library which does what you want to do and more. It is from Square Inc. and it is great. As the description of it says "Otto is an event bus designed to decouple different parts of your application while still allowing them to **communicate efficiently.**"

http://square.github.io/otto/

If you do not want to use it you can easily use `Broadcasts`. You can send a broadcast from one `Activity` and catch the broadcast from the other with `BroadcastReceiver` and update the UI accordingly. You can also send data with Intents in the broadcast so you can understand from the other `Activity` what you want to change exactly.

Comment: Please at least include the summary description of what that library does from the target of that link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) to start the activity B and after the user finishes to edit the options, you can return to A and send it back your data using the `Intent`.

**Edit:**
You could also use a `singleton` to store some values and have access to them in all your activities but please pay attention when using singletons as you can do memory leaks..

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible using [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). Register a BroadcastReceiver in first activity to listen for various broadcasts you want to send to it to update it's UI and send those broadcasts when you press buttons in the second activity. You can send data via broadcast using bundle.

Answer (score 1):

**case 1:**

you want to send some data from `A` to `B` at the beginning. Just use `Intent.putExtra` to pass data. From `B` recognize the data and do things

**case 2:**

you want to do some tasks in `A` when the `B` is finished. Just start `B` using `startActivityForResult` From `A` and when `B` finishes the `onActivityResult` will be called.

**case 3:**

You want to pass info (or order to call a method) in between two running activity. You can use `BroadcastMessage` (or `LocalBroadCastMessage`) to send Broadcast to other activity. read the message the do as it is instructed

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a slight misunderstanding of what [`Activities`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) are and how they work. The Activity is an "isolated" part of your Application, usually containing the current window and its contents. Each Activity used in this way keeps track of its own data, and interact with other Activities using [`Intents`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) or [`Broadcasts`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). As you mention, Activities can also access shared data from the [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) but also files or the [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) (or a singleton). You can not call a non-static method in another Activity since there is no guarantee that that Activity exists at the current moment.

If what you want to do is keep two "activities" active at the same time and frequently interacting with each other, you should probably switch to [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)s. You can have multiple Fragments in one Activity, and can thus interact much more freely (the preferred way is to communicate through the Activity).